# How do you post a form with ajax in php?

Tags: ajax, forms, ajaxform

I'm trying to use ajax to submit a form but I set it when it's successful a jquery alert should show but it's not showing so I think it's unsuccessful. Do you guys know why??

this is the form I'm trying to submit with ajax

```
<b>Product Title: </b><br><input style="width: 50%;" class="form-control itemtitle" type="text" name="title" required="true"><br>
<b>Product Description: </b><br><input style="width: 50%;" class="form-control itemdescription" type="text" name="description" required="true"><br>
<b>Product Price: </b><br><input style="width: 50%;" class="form-control itemprice" type="number" name="price" required="true"><br>
<b>Product Image Address: </b><br><input style="width: 50%;" class="form-control itemimageaddress" type="text" name="image" required="true"><br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary createproductsubmit">Create Product</button>
```

this is the ajax I'm using

```
$(".createproductsubmit").click(function(){
    var itemtitle = $(".itemtitle").val();
    var itemdescription = $(".itemdescription").val();
    var itemprice = $(".itemprice").val();
    var itemimageaddress = $(".itemimageaddress").val();

    var dataString = "itemtitle=" + itemtitle + "&itemdescription=" + itemdescription + "&itemprice=" + itemprice + "&itemimageaddress=" + itemimageaddress;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pages/newproductaction.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result)
        {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use

```
$.post("pages/newproductaction.php", {
itemtitle: itemtitle,
itemdescription: itemdescription,
itemprice: itemprice,
itemimageaddress: itemimageaddress
}, function(data){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments on your code.

1) You should be surrounding the form input and button elements with a `<form>` tag.
2) Instead of passing a string with a POST request, just pass an object like this:

```
data: {
    itemtitle: itemtitle,
    itemdescription: itemdescription,
    itemprice: itemprice,
    itemimageaddress: itemimageaddress
}
```

3) The alert() is not a jquery function but a pure javascript function. I recommend you use the console.log() and see outputs in the console.

4) Check the console for possible javascript errors. If you have a js error, the code won't even trigger the ajax call.

5) Check on the **Dev tools Network** tab and see if the ajax request is being sent. Check it reaches the right destination and check what the server response is.

Checking all this you should be in the right path.